# Black Background on image loaded with univerisal image loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

As shown  below. The first image is the default image  linked at http://goldentrail.towardstech.com/assets/images/membersimage/buttons/eat.png. while the second image below it is the image that is loaded using uil

This is the imageloader configuration

```
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
            .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
            .taskExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
            .taskExecutorForCachedImages(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
            .threadPoolSize(3) // default
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
            .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .discCacheFileCount(100)
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
            .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder()) // default
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
            .enableLogging()
            .build();
```

this is the displayoptions

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // default
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()

    .build();
```

[image]

Comment: Are you displaying images in ListView or GridView?? Then show your raw file here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you see comment in Readme:

```
DON'T COPY THIS CODE TO YOUR PROJECT! This is just example of ALL options using.
```

Don't use `.discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)`.
Your images saved in disc cache as JPEG files which can't have transparent background.

Comment: Yes, try something like `.discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.PNG, 75, null)` if you use PNG. Otherwise disable caches.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to uninstall the app. It was taking images from cache.

Comment: It's deprecated now, any workaround? (There is even no class CompressFormat in UIL)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/). This API helps with images and some others works with android.